# Increase height of UINavigationBar and add custom view that persists upon push

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

In my app, I'm currently using the standard `UINavigationController`, and pushing several controllers onto the navigation stack. Now, I need the ability to show a custom `UIView` (or `UIToolbar even) underneath the`UINavigationBar` and make it persist even after pushing a new view controller, and remove this view on demand. Very similar to the song info and controls in the iTunes Store:

[image]

Right now I'm just adding this view to the top view controller's `view` as a subview, so when a push is performed this custom view is no longer visible. Another problem is that this custom view overlaps the view controller's `view` content.

Is there a way to implement a custom navigation bar, extend its height, and add a subview? Then of course remove the subview and shrink the height when the view should no longer be shown? Or add a view underneath the navigation bar, automatically updating the content insets everywhere to not lie underneath it? Or how else could this be accomplished?

I looked into Apple's sample code for custom navigation bars. They have an extended height example with a custom view, but they did this by adding the view to a single view controller's view, so pushing would not preserve it.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the view to the navigation controller itself, but you'd have to handle animations yourself during a transition between views.

`[self.navigationController.view addSubview:overlayView];`